# Print method that shows groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Using `dplyr`, one can easily see the groups by which a dataset is grouped. How can one get these groups using `data.table` or define a print method that shows them.
Example:

```
df <- read.table(text = "X  Y Goal
32 12 1
                 13 42 0
                 55 33 0", header = TRUE)
setDT(df)
df[,lapply(.SD,sum),.(X,Y)][]
```

Output:

```
  X  Y Goal
1: 32 12    1
2: 13 42    0
3: 55 33    0
```

Doing something similar in `dplyr` provides a more visual display of the groups, how can I see the same in `data.table`?

**UPDATE**: Indeed as @Gregor points out below,the`summaris(z)e`
 family from `dyplr` automatically ungroups. However, how could I get `data.table` to print something like shown below.

Sample `dplyr` output. A `data.table` alternative of the statement `# Groups:   Species [3]` is precisely what I'm looking for.

```
 library(dplyr)
  iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) 

    # A tibble: 150 x 5
    # Groups:   Species [3]
   #    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
   #           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
   #  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
   #  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
   #  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
   #  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa
```

Thanks!

Comment: I could be super wrong here, but isn't the `data.table` equivalent of `group_by` `setkey`? So just `key(DT)` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Axeman not sure. I would think grouping is done using `by` and `keyby`. Although `setkey` also appears to do grouping for sorting tasks.

Comment: The difficulty is that `by=` groups are not retained as an attribute of the table, so the print method cannot be aware of them. If you do `keyby=` instead, there is some discussion of printing those https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1523 You might also be interested in dtq, which saves queries https://jangorecki.github.io/blog/2015-06-03/dtq.html

Comment: Use `.BY` to get a list of grouping columns

Comment: Could you add your code for "something similar in dplyr" to the Q, so we can see easily what your expected output is.

Comment: @dww I've added this.

Comment: @NelsonGon I don't think that's a good example... and I actually think this is based on somewhat of a false premise. Your `dplyr` example doesn't *do* anything but group. The equivalent `dplyr` code to your `data.table` code is `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize_all(sum)`, which doesn't print any grouping information either. (Since `summarize` drops the last-added grouping variable, the result is no longer grouped.)

Comment: oh @Gregor sorry. I just read and edited without looking back at my `data.table` example.  I'll reedit. Actually, the output is( I think) based on `tibble` although this seems to be the default print method for `dplyr` `group_by`.

Comment: I think that Frank's point will be difficult to work around---groups are *never* retained in `data.table`, they are used but never saved. Meanwhile the `dplyr` mechanism for grouped operations is to save them as an attribute, but the grouping is still modified by functions (like `summarize`) other than the explicit `group_by` and `ungroup` functions. I think you will be equally challenged to write `dplyr` code that prints groups that is equivalent to your `data.table` example.

Comment: You can add names to your grouping variables in `data.table`.  Maybe that achieves what you want? Something like `df[,lapply(.SD,sum),.(group.X = X, group.Y = Y)][]`

Comment: Fyi, if you like data.table for some reason other than its interface, you can load the dtplyr package and continue with grammar-of-data-manip verbs: `data.table(iris) %>% group_by(Species)` -- has class grouped_dt and should be manipulable in ways that take advantage of data.table backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, consider base R's `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) using `identity` if objective is as title reads and OP's specific needs below:

> Print method that shows groups 
>  
>   ...one can easily see the groups by which a dataset is grouped

In fact, you can run any operation like `summary` and `by` outputs still have group headers with section breaks!

```
# ONE GROUP
by(df, random_df$group, identity)

# TWO GROUPS
with(df, by(random_df, list(group1, group2), identity))

# THREE GROUPS
with(df, by(random_df, list(group1, group2, group3), identity))
```

---

Below is demonstration with random, seeded data:

### **Random Data**

```
set.seed(3222018)
data_tools <- c("sas", "stata", "spss", "python", "r", "julia")

random_df <- data.frame(
  group = sample(data_tools, 50, replace=TRUE),
  int = sample(1:5, 50, replace=TRUE),
  num = rnorm(50),
  char = rep(letters[1:3], 20)[1:50],
  bool = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50, replace=TRUE),
  data = as.Date(sample(1:as.integer(Sys.Date()), 50, replace=TRUE), origin="1970-01-01")  
)
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/TEMHO20299)

### One Group

```
by(random_df, random_df$group, identity)

# random_df$group: julia
#    group int         num char  bool       data
# 9  julia   1  0.55209060    c  TRUE 2003-01-08
# 12 julia   5  0.25581573    c FALSE 1973-01-20
# 20 julia   2 -0.44872825    b FALSE 1981-12-20
# 30 julia   1  0.09790121    c  TRUE 1981-07-11
# 31 julia   1  1.75711081    a FALSE 1984-05-23
# 35 julia   3 -1.78797757    b  TRUE 1992-10-23
# 39 julia   5 -1.83548253    c  TRUE 1982-04-18
# 44 julia   3  0.52640304    b FALSE 2016-07-28
# 50 julia   2  0.05759068    b FALSE 1987-07-09
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   random_df$group: python
#     group int         num char  bool       data
# 8  python   3 -0.75471461    b  TRUE 2018-04-08
# 15 python   4  0.03756282    c FALSE 2006-03-29
# 19 python   1  0.43025626    a FALSE 2005-03-30
# 22 python   4 -0.28019319    a FALSE 1997-02-19
# 24 python   2 -0.05318753    c FALSE 1977-08-02
# 45 python   2 -0.11575270    c  TRUE 2006-06-23
# 48 python   2 -0.29651827    c  TRUE 2015-07-13
# 49 python   3 -0.45816745    a FALSE 1991-09-09
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   random_df$group: r
#    group int        num char  bool       data
# 5      r   4 -0.1748250    b FALSE 2005-04-20
# 14     r   2 -0.5868782    b  TRUE 2005-12-30
# 25     r   5 -0.5108906    a  TRUE 1985-08-26
# 33     r   1  0.3580581    c FALSE 1983-08-16
# 34     r   3 -2.9556022    a  TRUE 1998-07-24
# 36     r   5 -2.5008645    c  TRUE 1990-12-30
# 43     r   5 -2.1710319    a  TRUE 1987-09-29
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   ...
```

### Two Groups

```
with(random_df, by(random_df, list(group, char), identity))

# : julia
# : a
#    group int      num char  bool       data
# 31 julia   1 1.757111    a FALSE 1984-05-23
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : python
# : a
#     group int        num char  bool       data
# 19 python   1  0.4302563    a FALSE 2005-03-30
# 22 python   4 -0.2801932    a FALSE 1997-02-19
# 49 python   3 -0.4581675    a FALSE 1991-09-09
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : r
# : a
#    group int        num char bool       data
# 25     r   5 -0.5108906    a TRUE 1985-08-26
# 34     r   3 -2.9556022    a TRUE 1998-07-24
# 43     r   5 -2.1710319    a TRUE 1987-09-29
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : sas
# : a
#    group int        num char  bool       data
# 28   sas   2 -0.6086176    a FALSE 2019-01-26
# 40   sas   4  0.5408948    a FALSE 2004-10-24
# 46   sas   1  0.7266734    a  TRUE 1996-09-05
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : spss
# : a
#    group int         num char  bool       data
# 1   spss   1 -0.06494476    a  TRUE 1999-07-10
# 7   spss   5  1.93460991    a  TRUE 1974-04-17
# 16  spss   1 -0.55380012    a FALSE 2010-04-06
# 37  spss   1  0.17309091    a  TRUE 1999-01-22
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : stata
# : a
#    group int        num char bool       data
# 4  stata   1 -1.0498222    a TRUE 1981-05-01
# 10 stata   1  1.9223104    a TRUE 1996-07-23
# 13 stata   1 -0.8381546    a TRUE 1989-01-12
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# ...
```

### Three Groups

```
with(random_df, by(random_df, list(group, char, int), identity))

# : julia
# : a
# : 1
#    group int      num char  bool       data
# 31 julia   1 1.757111    a FALSE 1984-05-23
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : python
# : a
# : 1
#     group int       num char  bool       data
# 19 python   1 0.4302563    a FALSE 2005-03-30
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : r
# : a
# : 1
# NULL
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : sas
# : a
# : 1
#    group int       num char bool       data
# 46   sas   1 0.7266734    a TRUE 1996-09-05
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : spss
# : a
# : 1
#    group int         num char  bool       data
# 1   spss   1 -0.06494476    a  TRUE 1999-07-10
# 16  spss   1 -0.55380012    a FALSE 2010-04-06
# 37  spss   1  0.17309091    a  TRUE 1999-01-22
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# : stata
# : a
# : 1
#    group int        num char bool       data
# 4  stata   1 -1.0498222    a TRUE 1981-05-01
# 10 stata   1  1.9223104    a TRUE 1996-07-23
# 13 stata   1 -0.8381546    a TRUE 1989-01-12
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# ...
```

---

### data.table example

To illustrate, you can also run *any* operation inside `by` including `data.table` aggregation to still return grouped headers and section breaks print output:

```
library(data.table)
...

by(random_df, random_df$group, function(sub)

  data.table(sub)[, list(mean_num = mean(num),
                         median_num = median(num),
                         min_num = min(num),
                         max_num = max(num),
                         total_num = sum(num)), by = char]
)

# random_df$group: julia
#    char   mean_num median_num   min_num   max_num total_num
# 1:    c -0.2324187  0.1768585 -1.835483 0.5520906 -0.929675
# 2:    b -0.4131780 -0.1955688 -1.787978 0.5264030 -1.652712
# 3:    a  1.7571108  1.7571108  1.757111 1.7571108  1.757111
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   random_df$group: python
#    char   mean_num  median_num    min_num     max_num  total_num
# 1:    b -0.7547146 -0.75471461 -0.7547146 -0.75471461 -0.7547146
# 2:    c -0.1069739 -0.08447011 -0.2965183  0.03756282 -0.4278957
# 3:    a -0.1027015 -0.28019319 -0.4581675  0.43025626 -0.3081044
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   random_df$group: r
#    char   mean_num median_num    min_num    max_num  total_num
# 1:    b -0.3808516 -0.3808516 -0.5868782 -0.1748250 -0.7617031
# 2:    a -1.8791749 -2.1710319 -2.9556022 -0.5108906 -5.6375247
# 3:    c -1.0714032 -1.0714032 -2.5008645  0.3580581 -2.1428064
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   random_df$group: sas
#    char    mean_num  median_num    min_num   max_num  total_num
# 1:    c  0.08215953 0.163064560 -1.3670420 1.3695510  0.3286381
# 2:    b -0.16423225 0.005903355 -1.3995380 0.7308023 -0.6569290
# 3:    a  0.21965022 0.540894826 -0.6086176 0.7266734  0.6589507
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   random_df$group: spss
#    char   mean_num  median_num    min_num    max_num total_num
# 1:    a  0.3722390  0.05407307 -0.5538001  1.9346099  1.488956
# 2:    b  0.5085635  0.73430008 -0.3003130  0.8659667  2.034254
# 3:    c -1.2909541 -1.29095413 -1.2909541 -1.2909541 -1.290954
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   random_df$group: stata
#    char    mean_num median_num    min_num    max_num  total_num
# 1:    a  0.01144453 -0.8381546 -1.0498222  1.9223104  0.0343336
# 2:    b -0.65927260 -0.6592726 -1.1870952 -0.1314500 -1.3185452
# 3:    c  0.94910811  0.9491081  0.9491081  0.9491081  0.9491081
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. How can I place this in (a) `data.table`?!

Comment: As mentioned, this solution attempts to answer your titled need: *Print method that shows groups*. I am not sure why you need *inside* a `data.table`. In fact, as mentioned, you can run *any* data operation including `data.table` ones inside `by` (extend *function* arg) to still print group headers and section breaks. See extended edit.

Comment: OK, maybe next time I'll have a more informative title.

Answer (score 1):

`# Groups:   Species [3]` is not printed by `dplyr`. It is in print method of `tibble`.

You can check/imitate it:

```
> a = iris
> # Set "Groups"
> setattr(a, "vars", "this_is_a_test_group") 
> # lie that it is a grouped_df
> setattr(a, "class", c("grouped_df","tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 
> 
> a
# A tibble: 150 x 5
# Groups:   this_is_a_test_group [?]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Count of groups `Species [3]` (`[3]`) is controlled by `indices` attribute.

It is a nested list of row indices for each group.

```
> setattr(a, "indices", list(1:5, 5:10, 10:15))
> a
# A tibble: 150 x 5
# Groups:   this_is_a_test_group [3]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 140 more rows
```

This doesn't really answer your question specifically. But demonstrating it in comments would be harder..

To get an output like that (with `groups[n]` before actual data.table) you will have to write a new print method that is a wrapper on top of data.table print, but prints those "vars" attributes before calling data.table print. 
And create a new class like "custom.groupped.data.table" that will use that print method.

Or attach those attributes and turn it into tibble object.

**EDIT:**

well, apparently some of that functionality is already implemented in data.table print method (but not turned on by default).

specifically: `print.keys = TRUE`

```
> b = data.table(iris)
> setkey(b, "Species")
> print(b, print.keys = TRUE)
Key: <Species>
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                            
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
> print(b, print.keys = TRUE, class = TRUE)
Key: <Species>
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
            <num>       <num>        <num>       <num>    <fctr>
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                            
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

Comment: Yeah, though keys are not the same thing as `by=` groups. Re the `n`, there's an open issue for keeping that as an attribute https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2879 (the uniqueN item)